# pass by value to be made into pass by pointer-perl code

Tags: perl

I have a function call like this below:

```
Send(0x39,((rLoss>>8)&0xFF),(rLoss&0xFF) );
```

I want to convert this function to pass by pointer. I have written two macros like

```
BYTE0(var)  ((uint8_t *)&var)
BYTE1(var)  ((uint8_t)&var)+1)
```

I want the result to be

```
Send(0x39,BYTE1(rLoss),BYTE0(rLoss) );
```

Can you please help me do this in perl... Thanks....

Comment: Questions seeking debugging help ("**why isn't this code working?**") must include the desired behavior, a *specific problem or error* and *the shortest code necessary* to reproduce it **in the question itself**. Questions without **a clear problem statement** are not useful to other readers. See: How to create a [mcve].

Comment: What are you talking about? That's not Perl code. I looks like C. Is this data that you want to transform using Perl?

Comment: It appears to me that the ambiguity in the question was due to English not being the author's first language.  Once I understood the.example code was data to be parsed, I found it to be an interesting question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I presume that the first argument to the call is *always* a hex number that doesn't have to be examined or transformed.  I've also presumed that args 2 and 3 are always ANDed with 0xFF.  Finally, I've presumed that the function being called and the argument being shifted are simple words - i.e. match `\w+`.  With these presumptions, the following appears to do what you want;

```
use v5.12;

while (<>) {
    chomp ;
    if (/ ^ (\w+) \(  .* \) \s* ; $ /x) {
        my $call = $1 ;                            # function name being called
        s/ ^  \w+  \( //x ;                        # Strip off fn call and open paren
        s/ \) \s* ; \s* $ //x ;                    # Strip off close paren and semicolon
        my ($arg1 , $arg2 , $arg3) = split ',' ;   # split into arguements of the call

        my $new_args = join("," , $arg1 , transform($arg2) , transform($arg3)) ;
        say "$call($new_args );" ;
    }
    else {
        say $_ ;
    }
}


sub transform {
    $_ = shift ;
    my $replacement ;

    s/ ^ \s* \( //x;                    # Strip off opening paren
    s/ \) \s* $ //x;                    # Strip off closing paren
    s/ & 0xFF $ //x ;                   # Strip off ANDing all ones

    if (/^ \w+ $/x) {                   # Simple var name left?
        $replacement = "BYTE0(" . $_ . ")" ;
    }
    elsif (/ ^ \( (\w+) >> (\d+) \) $ /x) {   # var name shifted some number of bits
        my $var_name = $1 ;
        my $shift_size = $2 ;
        my $byte_num = $shift_size / 8 ;
        $replacement = "BYTE" . $byte_num . "(" . $var_name . ")" ;
    }
    else {
        warn "Dont understand '$_' on line $.\n";
        $replacement = $_ ;
    }
    return $replacement
}
```

Its unix filter style - input on STDIN, transformed output on STDOUT.  When I feed it this made up data;

```
hello
Send(0x39,((rLoss>>8)&0xFF),(rLoss&0xFF) );
world
Receive(0x12,(rWin&0xFF),((rWin>>16)&0xFF) );
bye
```

It spits out

```
hello
Send(0x39,BYTE1(rLoss),BYTE0(rLoss) );
world
Receive(0x12,BYTE0(rWin),BYTE2(rWin) );
bye
```

Hopefully, the inline comments explain the code.  The decision on whether to attempt to transform the line or leave it alone is based solely on the first regex - a word (fn call) followed by something in parentheses - this may or may not be what you want.  Perhaps you know that its always a call to "Send" in which case you can put that in the regex.

The only other thing you may not be familiar with is the integer division operator '/'.  This is used to translate the number of bits being shifted to the BYTE num macro call.